# Skype for Business Online 2016 UCWA

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

We have Skype for Business Online 2016 and we would like to integrate our bot (based on rasa) which has currently no built-in integration for Skype. Custom channel will be implemented in Python.

After doing research it seems that UCWA is the way to go if IM need to be send and received between our bot and S4BOnline. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform

The documentation states it applies to S4BO**2015** and not sure if S4BO**2016** is supported as well. Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see this on the website:

> **Applies to:** Skype for Business 2015

This only specifies version of SfB **Server** for which it is applied (as for now, Skype for Business Online runs Skype for Business Server 2015 under the hood). I don't think you'll find anywhere in the docs:

> **Applies to:** Skype for Business 2016

What you are confused about is the version of **client** The client version is (not sure if this is official naming but that's how they're usually called):

- 2015 for users with Office 2013 and Skype for Business UI applied
- 2016 for Office 2016 users

While checking compatibility you need to verify that Skype for Business Online is supported and if you develop any client-only solutions/add-ons you might want to make sure that Skype for Business 2016 is supported.

*Just a side note: keep in mind that Skype for Business Online is going to be replaced by Microsoft Teams (check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/faq-journey) for more info) so maybe it's worth to keep that in mind while choosing the technology for your new bot.*

---

Some links that might be helpful to start:

- [Developing UCWA applications for Skype for Business Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline)
- [Sending IM using UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/sendanim)
- [Example of UCWA-based bot for Skype for Business Online](https://github.com/kenakamu/UCWABot)

Comment: So, S4B Server 2015 is under the hood. Our client is S4B 2016.
We did quite a lot of research regarding Skype APIs for our setup but got confused as it seems that there are various possibilities and combinations.
Do you agree that UCWA is the required resource to send and receive messages between our bot and Skype?

Comment: I added some helpful links and one example of SfBO bot based on UCWA. And yes, it's required (there might be some other options which I don't know). Hope that it'll help you to start. Just a friendly reminder - if you find this answer useful, please remember to mark it as accepted!